# Xcode not loading images into my storyboard all of the sudden (blue question marks)

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

This is quite frustating. I've been working on this app for months full time when one day last week, the storyboards just stopped showing the images that I use to skin that app as seen here:

[image]

The images still show up in my apps on both the sim and device (I've deleted the apps and reinstalled them).

The one image down there is somethign I have added outside my normal media .

I've tried the following things (and more. I can't remember everything I've tried):
 - Clean and rebuild
 - Removing images from the project, clean, re-add them
 - Removing the storyboard from the project, clean, re-add. 
 - Selecting the control that uses an image and re-entering the image name
 - Closing xcode
 - Launching the project by double clicking
 - Launching the project via command line

Comment: When you removed the images, did you try remove reference only? If not try it that way and see if that works.

Comment: CM, yes. I've tried removing reference, fully deleting/restoring, and referencing files that dont' exist.

Comment: I have seen that only happening with some image formats and when they are transparent. Are those images png or other formats. If they are not pig then maybe converting them and reload the images may allow xcode to see them again. Just make sure you didn't change any settings in your storyboard by accident.

Comment: Ah, I've figured it out. When double clicking the project to open it, some "other" IDE opened it and stripped the "~iphone" from the image names. Calls to UIImage are smart enough to look for that and figure out, thus it works at runtime just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. When double clicking the project to open it, some "other" IDE opened it and stripped the "~iphone" from the image names. Calls to UIImage are smart enough to look for that and figure out, thus all load at runtime just fine.

Answer (score 0):

remove images from your app:
select images-> right click->delete->move to trash

and go to your project folder and if there image exist remove it from there also

and now copy all the images to your project.

this way will work fine..
yesterday same problem occurred with me.. i solved it this way..

Comment: Thanks, but I already figured out the problem. i had neglected to post it as the accepted answer. It was just a nested comment until now.